# How to move title on Appbar when scrolling

Tags: flutter

I wanna make flutter app.

How to make a moving title on appbar when scrolloing??

I attached app's status on GIF file.

Where do I need to set moving the title text?

I just make app like Uber app

[image: snap]

```html
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double sliderValue = 0.0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
              child: SliverAppBar(
                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled ,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                elevation: 0.0,
                expandedHeight: 100.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                    collapseMode: CollapseMode.none,
                    title: Text("Notification",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        )),
                  ),

              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Sample Text"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: used **silver Widgets**. google `SilverAppBar`

Comment: I already used that. but, I couldn't do anything.

In my opinion, I have to set "Flexible_space_bar.dart" file.

so, would you help me one more time?

Comment: flutter link SilverAppBar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9C5KMJKluE&vl=ko

Answer (score 0):

Have to use `CustomScrollView` widget

```
CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 48,
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Center(
          child: Text('sliver'),
        )),
      ],
    );
```